# MySQL Event scheduler every day start at 12 AM and continue work EVERY 15 MINUTE till 5 AM

Tags: mysql, events, triggers, mariadb, scheduler

CREATE EVENT every_day_1AM_to_5AM_data_insert
ON SCHEDULE    EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)
ENDS TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)+INTERVAL 5 HOUR ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
`Any insert query here`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support setting a start and end time for every day in the `SCHEDULE` clause. Instead you should create a stored procedure which gets called by your event and check in there if you are within the desired time window. Like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE my_worker(IN from_time TIME, IN to_time TIME)
BEGIN
  IF CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN from_time AND to_time THEN

  -- do your work here

  END IF;
END
```

And here the event:

```sql
CREATE EVENT every_day_data_insert
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY '15' MINUTE
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
    DO 
BEGIN
    CALL `my_worker`('00:30:00', '05:30:00');   --- from 12:30 AM to 5:30 AM
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice solution. Is it possible 12:30 AM to 5:30 AM. Is it possible to use minute also? If possible how can I do it?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how to do it. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Louis, you are awesome.

Comment: Hi @SheikhWasiuAlHasib if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Ok @Louis check it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, when an event starts running its query it continues until the query finishes. Your CREATE EVENT code says to start running the event at `CURRENT_DATE` (midnight local time on the present date -- a time likely to be already in the past). It says to stop repeating the event at 05:00 on the present day -- also a time likely to be in the past. So, I bet your event never runs.

You may want this to run the event at midnight.

```sql
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ENDS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
```

**Pro tip** Avoid running stuff exactly at midnight. Why? Everybody else does, and your event will have to compete with all the other midnight stuff. Try

```
STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 137 SECOND
```

to run it at some time a few seconds after midnight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to run this event everyday 1AM to 5 AM EVERY 15 minute interval. I think now it is clear to you. How can I do it?

Comment: CREATE EVENT test_event5
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY   EVERY 15 MINUTE 
  STARTS  TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 SECOND
  ENDS TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)+ INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 5 HOUR ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
  DO
   INSERT INTO messages(message,created_at) VALUES('Test MySQL recurring TEST_EVENT5 EVERY 1 DAY EVERY 15 MINUTE ENDS AFTER 5 HOUR',NOW());
  ) I want it like this but it is not right syntax as per mysql. I think you can help me on this.

Comment: Here I want to run same query every 15 min after in each day to do some task. If event ran for 1 time for every day then need to do it by stored procedure.